# Java, read from File

Tags: java

I have a very quick question.

I have a file name "1234.txt"

```
Betty Boop
BABAAAABAAAAAAABAAAABBAAAAAABAAAABABAABAAABABABAABAAAAAABAAAAAABAAAAAA
Snoopy
AABBAABBBBBABABAAAAABABBAABBAAAABBBAAABAABAABABAAAABAABBBBAAABBAABABBB
Bugs Bunny
AABAABBABBBAAAABAAAABAAAAABABBBAABAAAABAABBBBABAAAABAABAAAAAABBAAAAABB
Daffy Duck
BAAAAA-BAAAABABAAAAAABA-AAAABABAAAABAABAA-BAAABAABAAAAAABA-BAAABA-BAAA
The frumious bandersnatch
-BBABAA-BBBBBABBBBA-BABBBBBBBBBABBBBBBABB-BBBABBABBBBBBB-BABBBBBBBBBBB
Minnie Mouse
BABA-AABABBBAABAABA-ABABAAAB-ABAAAAAA-AAAABAAABAAABAAAAAB-ABBAAAAAAAAA
Luke Skywalker
BBBAAABBBBAABA-BAAAABBABBAAABBAABAAB-AAAAABBBABAABABA-ABBBABBABAA-AAAA
Han Solo
BA-ABABBB-BBBAABABAAAABBAAABBAAABBABABBAAABABBAAABABAAAABBABAAABBABAAB
Princess Leia
BABBAAABBBBAAABBA-AAAABABBABBABBAAABAABAAABBBA-AABAABAAAABAAAAABABBBAA
```

The first line is the name of the person, the second line is the personality of that person.

I want to capture the name, and personality into two different strings : name, getPersonal.
But I don't know how. The way I write it, all the text will go to name. So how to fix it?

This is my code:

```
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String name = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("name is here: " + name);

            String getPersonal = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(" personal is here " + getPersonal);

}
```

---

EDIT 1 : the system.out.println "name is here", and "personal is here" is just for testing if the code did what I expected it to do, here is to store the first line as name, the second line as personality and so on.

I want these two string to do another things.

If I run this code, it will show an error "No Line Found". Since all the text will go to name, there is no text for personality.

---

EDIT 2: Here is the output :

```
Enter the name of the file with the personality data: 
1234.txt
name is here: 
 personal is here Betty Boop
name is here: BABAAAABAAAAAAABAAAABBAAAAAABAAAABABAABAAABABABAABAAAAAABAAAAAABAAAAAA
 personal is here Snoopy
name is here: AABBAABBBBBABABAAAAABABBAABBAAAABBBAAABAABAABABAAAABAABBBBAAABBAABABBB
 personal is here Bugs Bunny
name is here: AABAABBABBBAAAABAAAABAAAAABABBBAABAAAABAABBBBABAAAABAABAAAAAABBAAAAABB
 personal is here Daffy Duck
name is here: BAAAAA-BAAAABABAAAAAABA-AAAABABAAAABAABAA-BAAABAABAAAAAABA-BAAABA-BAAA
 personal is here The frumious bandersnatch
name is here: -BBABAA-BBBBBABBBBA-BABBBBBBBBBABBBBBBABB-BBBABBABBBBBBB-BABBBBBBBBBBB
 personal is here Minnie Mouse
name is here: BABA-AABABBBAABAABA-ABABAAAB-ABAAAAAA-AAAABAAABAAABAAAAAB-ABBAAAAAAAAA
 personal is here Luke Skywalker
name is here: BBBAAABBBBAABA-BAAAABBABBAAABBAABAAB-AAAAABBBABAABABA-ABBBABBABAA-AAAA
 personal is here Han Solo
name is here: BA-ABABBB-BBBAABABAAAABBAAABBAAABBABABBAAABABBAAABABAAAABBABAAABBABAAB
 personal is here Princess Leia
name is here: BABBAAABBBBAAABBA-AAAABABBABBABBAAABAABAAABBBA-AABAABAAAABAAAAABABBBAA
 personal is here Captain America
name is here: BBAA-BABAAABAABAABAAABBABABABAAA-ABBAAABAABAAABAABABA-AA-AAAAAABB-ABAA
 personal is here No Answer Dude
name is here: ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Error:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
at Capitalize.getName(Capitalize.java:49)
at Capitalize.main(Capitalize.java:26)
```

So how to fix it to take these lines into appropriate string?

---

EDIT 3: So I know why you guys see it works fine and mine is not. I forgot to put the "actual" first line.

```
11
Betty Boop
BABAAAABAAAAAAABAAAABBAAAAAABAAAABABAABAAABABABAABAAAAAABAAAAAABAAAAAA
Snoopy
AABBAABBBBBABABAAAAABABBAABBAAAABBBAAABAABAABABAAAABAABBBBAAABBAABABBB
Bugs Bunny
AABAABBABBBAAAABAAAABAAAAABABBBAABAAAABAABBBBABAAAABAABAAAAAABBAAAAABB
Daffy Duck
BAAAAA-BAAAABABAAAAAABA-AAAABABAAAABAABAA-BAAABAABAAAAAABA-BAAABA-BAAA
The frumious bandersnatch
-BBABAA-BBBBBABBBBA-BABBBBBBBBBABBBBBBABB-BBBABBABBBBBBB-BABBBBBBBBBBB
Minnie Mouse
BABA-AABABBBAABAABA-ABABAAAB-ABAAAAAA-AAAABAAABAAABAAAAAB-ABBAAAAAAAAA
Luke Skywalker
BBBAAABBBBAABA-BAAAABBABBAAABBAABAAB-AAAAABBBABAABABA-ABBBABBABAA-AAAA
Han Solo
BA-ABABBB-BBBAABABAAAABBAAABBAAABBABABBAAABABBAAABABAAAABBABAAABBABAAB
Princess Leia
BABBAAABBBBAAABBA-AAAABABBABBABBAAABAABAAABBBA-AABAABAAAABAAAAABABBBAA
```

Yes, it's an INT. So how can I skip that int ? and proceed to the next line?

---

EDIT 4 : I'M A STUPID OK? DON't LAUGH AT ME. I'M A TOTALLY NEWBIE. THANKS !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: What gets assigned to `name`?

Comment: What is the output you get, what is the output you expect? Why do you think the code is doing what you said in your question? Can you post a complete, compilable example that shows the problem you are running into?

Comment: Can you show us the output from your program please?

Comment: Your code works fine for me (assuming that `input` is `Scanner`) so I suspect that problem might be in other part of your code that you are not showing us.

Comment: Are you sure that there's an actual line break after the first line, and not just word-wrap in whatever editor you're using?

Comment: Where is the code that displays "No line found"? Without seeing the code, we can't explain what it does and why it does it.

Comment: You've probably got an extra blank line at the beginning of your file.  Please check this.

Comment: What's makes you not posting the real file data!!!!!

Comment: @hasan I COPY PASTE IT AND SOMEHOW I LEFT THE FIRST LINE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("name is here: " + name);

        String getPersonal = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(" personal is here " + getPersonal);

}
```

You're testing if the file has **one** next line, and if it has **one** next line, you're reading the **two** next lines.

It seems your file has an odd number of lines (the file ends with a line made of dashes, as the output shows), so the last iteration tries to read a line that doesn't exist.

EDIT:

To read a line and skip it: read it:

```
input.nextLine();
// now start looping to read the lines you really want to read
```

Answer (score 0):

When you read that `int` (and I'm presuming you're using `nextInt()` for this), call `nextLine()` afterwards; because `nextInt()` does not read the new line character that occurs after the number.